# how to include a column from a second table in my LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a table called `Ad` (advertisement):

```
public class Ad
{
    public long AdId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; } // <-- this is advertiser not currentUser
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Users can add zero or more advertisements to their favourites list, so I have created another table called `Favourite`:

```
public class Favourite
{
    public long FavouriteId { get; set; }
    public long AdId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a table called `User`:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I retrieve an ad, given `currentUserId` and `adId`:

```
public TEntity GetAd(long currentUser, long adId)
{
    return Context.Ad
        .Where(r.AdId == adId)
        // include a flag indicating the pair (adId and currentUserId) exist in Favouries table
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

What I want to include in the result is a flag, indicating if the ad is added to the favourites list or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In Entity Framework we have navigation properties. You can define navigation property on child table for the parent table row. For you case you can change your child entity like following:</strike>

```
public class Favourite
{
    public long FavouriteId { get; set; }
    public long AdId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
}
```

and now the Entity Framework should take care of populating it for you and you can access the `Ad` related row of `Favourite` like :

```
return Context.Ad
        .Where(r => r.UserId == userId && r.AdId == adId)
        .Select(x => x.Ad.Description);
```

But in your case, You can write a query to know if the ad is favourite or not:

```
return Context.Ad
        .Where(r.AdId == adId)
        Select(x => new 
                   { 
                      ad = x, 
                      IsFavourite = Context.Favourite.Any(y=> y.AdId = adId 
                                                    && y.UserId = currentUserid))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

you can create a Domain View Model and map it to that :

```
public UserFavouriteAd
{
    public Ad Ad { get; set; }
    public IsFavourite { get; set; }
}
```

and populate it:

```
return Context.Ad
            .Where(r.AdId == adId)
            .ToList()
            Select(x => new UserFavouriteAd 
                       { 
                          ad = x, 
                          IsFavourite = Context.Favourite.Any(y=> y.AdId = adId 
                                                        && y.UserId = currentUserid))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks a lot. So you are recommend adding IsFavouries flag to a new type? it makes sense to me... it maybe easier to return Ad (including IsFavourite) but at the same time, the flag does not really belong to Ad Entity.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini yes i think adding a new class makes sense, as the table does not have the column physically it's just logical for your business logic.

Comment: if you would need only favourite ads of user then the navigation property is straightforward, just adding `Ad` in `Favourite` to link with `AdId`

Comment: I want to display the ad regardless of being favourite or not. If it is in favourites, then put a "heart" icon next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public object GetAd(long currentUser, long adId)
{
    return from a in Context.Favourite
           where a.UserId  == currentUser
           select new {
                      flag = a.AdId != null
                      a.FavouriteId,
                      //etc
                      };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work... but then I need to make 2 trips to the DB, I wanted to get everything at one go.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini you need to set up navigation properties then